# I am using multiple firebase projects in an Android App. I am getting this error : Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, multiple-projects

I have added following code to initialise there projects.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:129574837465:android:0123456773a52cf4f6") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("iubdeibneh8gzDt7Xn9f-jdjjdjdjdj") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://databasename-d7r7.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context /* Context */, options, "secondary");


FirebaseOptions options2 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:129574837465:android:0123456773a52cf4f6") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("iubdeibneh8gzDt7Xn9f-jdjjdjdjdj") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://databasename2-d7r7.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context /* Context */, options2, "secondary2");


FirebaseOptions options3 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:129574837465:android:0123456773a52cf4f6") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("kjdkj-o_3nk4jn4k3kjk23j") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://databasename3-d7r7.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context /* Context */, options3, "secondary3");
```

After initialisation my app is running fine. I can use FirebaseAuth, and FirebaseRTDB just fine but it is throwing error when it has to access firebase_Application_Id for analytics.

I have cross checked the ids from google-services.json files of all the projects. I don't know why but it throws error saying:

```
Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
```

I couldn't figure out the root of this error.

Comment: redownload the google-services.json again and rebuild your project

Comment: I did that. It is not working !

Comment: The docs say "Note: On Android and iOS, Firebase Analytics are only logged for the default app." https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/, have you check that?

Comment: @mark922 Have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you double check if google-services.json is located at your Android app module root directory?

[image]

If it is there, make sure google-services.json has the mobilesdk_app_id key. It should be located under the client_info node.

```
 {
   ...,
   "client": [
     {
        "client_info": {
          "mobilesdk_app_id": "random_string",
          ...
        }
     }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: Yes. I cross checked it again. It is in the proper location and "mobilesdk_app_id":"VALUE" is also there.

Comment: The main problem was I wanted to initialise the default firebase project programmatically. I have to use at least one google-services.json file to initialise the default project. Here is how the firebase initialises itself : [How does Firebase initialize on Android?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html).

Answer (score 37):

In my case the problem was with incomplete Firebase configuration.

I was missing

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    ...
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

from build.gradle.

And

```
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

from app/build.gradle.

Comment: Thanks! `// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM` also works at the top. Fixed it for me.

Comment: Adding this solve my connection issue too. I am looking at the FlutterFire tutorial on the setup, but do no realize I need to update the Android project too. It seems FlutterFire CLI didn't help me to auto add this line and the tutorial didn't emphasis me to add back this lines.

Comment: This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6):

The issue could be due to `instant app` being enabled

Solution : 
Manually add **google_app_id** to the **strings.xml** file — [as told here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/issues/44#issuecomment-378103468)

[image]

Update : In case app crashes without any warning or error, try this (maven):

Go to project level `build.gradle` & check if it looks exactly like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

and the code suddenly works and when you'll look at other answers you will find the same.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize FirebaseApp early in OnCreate() using APP ID and Client key:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
       .setApplicationId("1:530266078999:android:481c4ecf3253701e") // Required for Analytics.
       .setApiKey("AIzaSyBRxOyIj5dJkKgAVPXRLYFkdZwh2Xxq51k") // Required for Auth.
       .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-1765055333176374514.firebaseio.com/") // Required for RTDB.
       .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary");
```

Source: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: you just leaked your API key 

Answer (score 1):

[@Anton Malyshev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447402/812973) 's answer is correct.

**↓ project gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    ...
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

**↓ app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Manually add `google_app_id` to the `strings.xml` file like:

[image]

You can get `google_app_id` from `google-services.json`, in which it is defined as `mobilesdk_app_id`.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I increased the gradle version from
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'` to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.3.8'
```

in build.gradle project level and the problem disappeared